# Creating Fence Diagrams from Electromagnetic (EM) Conductance Survey

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, spatial-analyst, 3d-analyst, subsurface

I am looking for some help with creating fence diagrams in GIS for Electromagnetic Conductance surveys. I have points along a line that represent sample locations with three different depths (readings) at each location. My goal is to try to create something like a fence diagram along the sample routes using the conductivity results at each of the sample points.

I have a couple pieces of literature as reference, but they are geared more towards geologic modeling. The first is "Tools and Techniques for 3D Geologic Mapping in ArcScene: Boreholes, Cross Section, and Block Diagrams" http://pubs.usgs.gov/of/2014/1167/pdf/ofr2014-1167_carrell-tools-and-techniques.pdf. The second is "Digital Mapping and 3D Visualization/Modelling of Subsurface Geology UsingArcGIS 9.2 and Well Log Data" https://www.scribd.com/doc/3982961/8/How-to-Create-a-Fence-Diagram.

The literature is somewhat helpful but not exactly what I was looking for.

I will be trying to use ArcMap/ArcScene 10.1 with access to 3D Analyst and Spatial Analyst.

Comment: Hi, welcome to GIS.stackexchange, at the moment your question is rather broad. Are you looking for instructions on making these kinds of maps, published examples of them? Asking if someone has done X, isn't really suited to the SE format: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you included the "pieces of literature as reference" that you mention within your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath it that you can use to improve your question at any time.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried to update the text a little more and include the links to the literature I found as reference.

Comment: I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Comment: I will be sure I rephrase my post next time I try to look for help with something. Would you prefer I just delete this post?